# Pre-Sort DataGrid Column in Powershell

Tags: wpf, powershell, datagrid

I am trying to pre-sort a column in a DataGrid inside of Powershell. I have created a DataGrid with XAML. I am populating the DataGrid with a DataTable in Powershell.

My current attempt:

```
$UI.DataGrid.DataContext = $DataContext

$DataContext = $DataTable.DefaultView | Sort-Object -Property 'Property 1'
```

However, when I run this, my DataGrid is filled with unnecessary columns such as: Row Version, Row, IsNew, IsEdit, and Error. I have been looking for a property or method that allows me to sort in both the DataTable and DataGrid objects. Unfortunately, I have been unable to find either that help me in this situation. I have been reading a bit on DataGridView options. Note: this is not a DataGridView, but a DataGrid.

Comment: `$DataContext = New-Object System.Data.DataView $DataTable, $null, 'Property 1', 'CurrentRows'`?

Comment: @PetSerAl This worked. Can you please show me how you found this solution? EDIT: It makes sense that you create a new 'DataView' object since DataView has a method 'Sort'. However, PowerShell ISE doesn't have the Sort method listed when you call Get-Member on $DataContext. Furthermore, I also don't understand where you discover the parameters that can be used when first calling the object.

Comment: I usually use ILSpy (I prefer it over MSDN, but it is not a tool for everyone) for inspecting .NET assemblies. So, first I go to `DataTable.DefaultView` property, then I look which constructors `DataView` class have and happens to find what I am looking for. Not sure what you mean by `Sort` method. `DataView` have `Sort` property. And it listed by `Get-Member -InputObject $DataContext`. You can discover constructor parameters in [corresponded MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8sd1cd0a.aspx).

Comment: @PetSerAl Excuse me, I thought that Sort would be a method because it had parameters. Ran `Get-Member -InputObject $DataContext` as well and I got the Sort in the result. It doesn't show up when I run `$DataContext | gm` - Why is that?  Thank you for responding.

Comment: As PowerShell enumerates collections when passed by pipeline, with `$DataContext | gm` you will get members of `DataRowView` not of `DataView`.